# Flicker of JFrames before moving locations

Tags: java, swing, jframe, centering

I noticed that most of my swing GUIs would flicker right before they center themselves. This happened with almost any JFrame that I have made, I was wondering if there is a workaround. I usually call `setVisible(true)`, then `pack()`, followed by `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`. This makes it appear in the top right and then center it self. I know that the flicker is happening because it's taking time for each method call, but is there a workaround for this (To make it nice and smooth)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This order (and these methods) are better:

1. `frame.pack();`
2. `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true); // superior to centering`
3. `frame.setVisible(true);`

If you set a number of frames visible doing that, they might appear something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556):

[image]

And of course, without any flicker, wobble *or* shake.  ;)

---

> The problem with that (`setLocationRelativeTo(null)`) is that the GUIs top right corner is centered and not the entire JFrame.

The defualt size of a `JFrame` is 0x0 and it stays that way until `pack()` or `setSize()` (but use `pack()` as you are doing currently) is called.  So if you ask for a 0x0 component to be centered on screen, the JRE will place the 'middle pixel' of the 0x0 sized component at the exact center of the screen.

Alternately if you pack it first it *has* the correct size, and the method will work as expected.  E.G.

```
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // show my splash screen!
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do first `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` and then `setVisible(true)` in the end.

Comment: The problem with that is that the GUIs top right corner is centered and not the entire JFrame.

Comment: `pack()` should be called ***before*** `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to make it centered.  I guess that is what GP Singh meant.  (But in my answer, I was more explicit about the order of method calls.)

Comment: See also the edit to my answer, which will hopefully explain what is going on.